# Where do I set permission to access the internal website?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, windows-server-2008

I am migrating a site internal servers, and I need you like the old server is requested network login and goes like display or not the site, how can I set this up, I believe it is in IIS

my version is 7.0

Comment: Can you please clarify your question again? Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course!
I have a server A (which was not set by me) that when trying to access the internal Web site and User password is requested network until all ok.
I'm migrating this same site to server B, but when trying to access the same login and password prompts not network (domain) must configure this step, but do not know how to do: (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different types of authentications you can setup in IIS 7.  [Please have a look at this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733010%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  It will guide you through the process of setting up the authentication you are looking for.

For Windows Authentication, this is what you will do:

- Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage.
- In Features View, double-click Authentication.
- On the Authentication page, select Windows Authentication.
- In the Actions pane, click Enable to use Windows authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure two options in IIS7 for website to be accessible through domain/windows authentication:

1. "Enable" Windows Authentication
2. "Disable" Anonymous Authentication

To reach to these options:
Open IIS Manager, select website to configue, on Right hand pane find "Authentication" option. You'll find these options to configure in this area.